# Octave to solve differential equations

Tags: octave, differential-equations

How do I solve the differential equation y'+y=t with y(0)=24?

Do I need to defined the differential equation with a file in the form .m?

Answer (score 2):

To solve ordinary differential equations you've got the function lsode (run lsode for help).

```
f = @(y,t) t-y;
t = linspace(0,5,50)';
y=lsode(f, 24, t);
plot(t,y);
print -djpg figure-lsnode.jpg
```

[image: y versus t]

Answer (score -1):

```
dy/dt + y = t
```

Multiply integrating factor `e^t` on both sides. Then,

```
d/dt [(e^t)y] = te^t
y = t-1+ce^(-t)
```

Because, `y(0)=24` then `c=25`

```
y = t-1+25e^(-t)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question on how to use GNU octave to solve this ODE or similar ones.